# I want to pass a list in a definition function to count the number of digits in a number that's in a list

Tags: python, function, integer

```
def count_digit(num):
    if (num//10 == 0):
        return 1
    else:
        return 1 + count_digit(num // 10)
```

i have a list called - filter_stats which looks like :

```
filter_stats= [1,2,24,2,353,4534,6,65,6457,6,8,58,58,744, and so on]
```

I want to pass this list in the code above. how do I do that?

when I did this

```
count_digit(filter_stats)
```

it shows this: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'filter' and 'int'

Comment: `count_digit()` only works with a single number. Use a loop or list comprehension to call it on a list of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop:

```
results = []
for num in filter_stats:
    results.append(count_digit(num))
```

A list comprehension is also an option:

```
results = [count_digit(num) for num in filter_stats]
```

Finally, you can also use `map` if you like functional approaches:

```
results = list(map(count_digit, filter_stats))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a list into the count_digit function.
So when you divide a list by "// 10", that would give an error.
To see the length of a number, you can use the len() function,
so e.g. len(str(123)).

So, in your code you have to pass in the list item :
e.g: count_digit(filter_stats[4])   => then it works!

you can simplify the function like this:

```
def count_digit(num):
    return len(str(num))
```

and then call the function :

```
count_digit(filter_stats[4])
```